# first year CS exam, need guidense

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, computer-science, abstract

i have my exams tomorrow in java. It is focus on encapsulation, cohesion, coupling, inheritance and interface. I made a project of seven classes, speaker and headset class inherits from sound class and product class and DjMixer implements just from product.The main class is still empty. I need to know if I'm making any crucial mistakes in my code design.

```
public interface Product
{

    double getPrice();

    void setPrice(double price);

    String getId();

    void setId(String Id);

    String getPlace();

    void setPlace(String place);
}

public abstract class Sound
{

public abstract void setDesibel(int desibel);

public abstract int getDesibel();

public void amp() {
        System.out.println("Recomended amplifier effect is 40-250 watts");
    }

}

public class Speaker extends Sound implements Product
{

    double price;
    String id;
    String place;
    int desibel;

    /**Price in Norwegain Kroner */    
public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    /**Price is set in Norwegain Kroner */ 
public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**Location of the product*/
public String getPlace(){
        return place;
    }

public void setPlace(String place){
        this.place = place;
    }

    /**The products European Article Number*/
public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    /**type in the European Article Number under the barcode*/
public void setId(String serialNum){
        id = serialNum;
    }

    //Constructor
public Speaker(double price, String location, String serialNum) {
        super.amp();
        this.price = price;
        place = location;
        id = serialNum;
    }

public int getDesibel() {
        return this.desibel;
    }

public void setDesibel(int desibel) {
        this.desibel = desibel;
    } 
}

public class Headset extends Sound implements Product
{

    double price;
    String place;
    String id;
    int desibel;
    boolean wireless = true;

    /**Price is in Norwegain Kroner */ 
public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    /**Price is set in Norwegain Kroner */ 
public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**Location of the product*/
public String getPlace(){
        return place;
    }

    /**Set location where item is stored */
public void setPlace(String location){
        place = location;
    }

    /**The products European Article Number*/
public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    /**type in the European Article Number under the barcode*/
public void setId(String serialNum){
        id = serialNum;
    }

    //Constructor
public Headset(double price, String location, String serialNum) {
        super();
        this.price = price;
        place = location;
        id = serialNum;
    }

public void setDesibel(int desibel) {
        this.desibel = desibel;
    }

public int getDesibel() {
        return this.desibel;
    }
}

public class DjMixer implements Product
{


    double price;
    String id;
    String place = "Storage room, shelf 3";

    /**Price in Norwegain Kroner */
public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    /**Price is set in Norwegain Kroner */ 
public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**Mixing tables is stored on shelf 3, if moved please set new place */
public String getPlace(){
        return place;
    }

    /**Set new place for mixing table if moved */
public void setPlace(String location){
        place = location;
    }

    /**The products European Article Number*/
public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    /**type in the European Article Number under the barcode*/
public void setId(String serialNum){
        id = serialNum;
    }

public DjMixer(double price, String serialNum){
        this.price = price;
        id = serialNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably belongs in CodeReview

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What has to do the C# tag here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to declare any variable that can be accessed via a "get" method as private. Also, you  put "desibel" instead of "decibel" in some of your methods. If your teacher has taught you the `final` keyword, the wireless `boolean` seems like it should be declared as such.